# Android: How do I split TableLayout row similar to "rowspan"

Tags: android, android-layout, validation

I have a table layout and i want to split a cell into two rows

below is my code

```
<TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:text="@string/cardiovascular_problems" />

            <Spinner android:id="@+id/cardiovascular_spinner"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:text="@string/if_yes_give_details" />

            </TableRow>
```

In this row I would like to have 2 cells. the 1st cell has a text view

the second cell i want to split it into two rows

the 1st row has a spinner and text view and the 2nd row has an edit text

Is there a way to do this other than using another table layout in this row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not have to be a TableLayout, you can put the second column items e.g. into a RelativeLayout. I doubt that it is possible to easily do it without nested layouts.